# How to power two motors using a single Li-po battery

Tags: mosfet, motor, switches, parallel

I'm trying to power two motors using a single Li-po battery.

On/Off control of motor 1 is to be through a MOSFET switch.

On/Off control of motor 2 is to be either through a MOSFET switch or a conventional SPST switch.

I intend wiring the motors as shown in the following schematic:

[image]

My question is whether it would work as desired.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this circuit? I can't tell you whether the circuit does what you want without you stating what is needed for it to do. Where did the circuit come from?

Comment: It's for a gel blaster. The trigger engages the mosfet switch, powering the motor. But I also want a separate, physical button to also engage the motor directly from the battery.

Basically, closing either switch (mosfet or physical) should engage the motor. Neither switch is expected to be closed at the same time.

Comment: I have no idea what a gel blaster is. What is "the trigger"? Like, what do you mean?

Comment: A gel blaster is a blaster that blasts gel. I think. Hmm. Sorry, I will get my coat and I will find my way out. No bouncers needed.

Comment: Literally what @KristoferA said.

Comment: I was trying to simplify the problem, which is a mistake I make every time I post a stack exchange question.  I've edited the question and title, hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: SW1 does absolutely nothing in your schematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your updated question, now you will need to add a diode.

In the schematic you can see that the motors are both connected to the positive of the battery, and low side switching is used to activate them by pulling their negative terminals low. The MOSFET pulls MOTOR 1 low directly, and MOTOR 2 low through an appropriately rated diode, so when the trigger is pressed the MOSFET turns on and powers both motors. The switch powers MOTOR 2, but the diode blocks it from powering MOTOR 1. This meets the requirements as currently stated.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMnyHO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes the whole thing is powered by a single battery. V+ is the voltage delivered to the motor by the MOSFET when it is closed. 

I don't necessarily have direct access to wire a switch in parallel with the MOSFET, as it's on a PCB. What I have are two pads it supplies that are in parallel with a different motor, and probably the voltage source, but I'm not sure.

Comment: So I think the full circuit is something like https://imgur.com/a/xOdw3d3, based off your schematic.  What I want is for motor 2 to be turned on by either a physical switch, OR the MOSFET, while Motor 1 is only turned on by the MOSFET

Comment: So maybe it's as simple as this https://imgur.com/a/hadFGEt, idk...

Comment: @MattS yeah I’ll fix my answer when I’m back on my desktop.

Comment: Well I wired it up as in my last diagram, and both motors spin with the switch closed, so idk. Not sure how to resolve

Comment: What's a ballpark appropriately rated diode? I'll try this.

Comment: @GeneralPancake That would depend on how much current your motors draw. You might want to look at Schottky diodes for lower voltage drop.

Comment: Nice this worked, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your schematic will not work, as required, as motor 2 will always be on.

The following schematic will satisfy your requirement:

[image]

Motor 1 is controlled by MOSFET1.

Motor 2 is controlled either by MOSFET2 or switch SW1.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I'd add some freewheeling diodes to the motors for completeness' sake.

Comment: @ Patrick Fiedler - Hi Patrick, Done, thank you.